# Clear button in input[text]

Tags: javascript, html, css

//May I have a very big problems in english, but I hope you'll understand.

In general, I tryed to use Marco's code, but I have a big problem with using an icon instead a text in button. I masked it, gave it a transparent background, deleted outline and borders. And it doesn't helped me. I solve it so:

```js
$(".clearbutton").click(function(){
  $(".clearable").val("");
});
```

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    text-align: center;  
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    text-align: center;  
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

input[type="text"] {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F1F1F1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: #ABABAB;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #ABABAB;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder       {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder                {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder                 {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder            {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus::-moz-placeholder          {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus:-moz-placeholder           {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}

.uitextbox {
  display: table;
}

.clearbutton {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="uitextbox">
            <input class="clearable" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
            <button class="clearbutton"><img src="icon.svg" width="15" height="15"></button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPD: Wow, that's working. Okay, but my first problem it's a position of button. She's isn't inside a box. My second problem it's what button is visible when box value is empty. However, I think, I can solve it. My third problem it's a decoration. I know how to get element fading effect. But, I don't know, how to do that on a button and box's text. And my hands is growing up out of the wrong place. For some reason I can't use external js file and when I using script inside of the html file, then it's working. May there some problems with my workspace? ._.-.

[This is how looks my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxzim.png)

.js file it's in the "js" folder, yeah

When I use external js file, it doesn't works. So I can't follow picture, just because I haven't so much reputation.

When I use js inside html, [it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cegb.gif).

Comment: See my answer to clear the first input of type text.

Answer (score 0):

The reset button and input need to be inside a form. Note that the reset button WILL reset the whole form.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <button type="reset" value="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm right, you want the button to be inside the input field.

This way:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".clearable").val("");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

html {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    text-align: center;  
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    text-align: center;  
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

input[type="text"] {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F1F1F1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: #ABABAB;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #ABABAB;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder       {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder                {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder                 {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder            {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus::-moz-placeholder          {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus:-moz-placeholder           {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}

div {
  display: table;
}
button {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -62px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <input class="clearable" type="text" placeholder="JUST TEXT BOX"/>
        <button>CLEAR</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks good, but it does not work for some reason with images. I tried different options. When I use "<img>", I get an icon, but nothing happens when I click. When I use "background: url", nothing happens at all. Boringly, in general. What I gonna do?

Comment: <img src=" "> with path between "

Comment: Uhm. I.e I need to set this? o.o :
<button><img src="icon.svg "></button>

Comment: Oh sorry i  exchanged your question with another ahahahaha can you explain me the issue?

Comment: Well, in general, when I use your code, I get the button right in the text box. It's good. But, as soon as I want to make it transparent and with a badge, it is not pressed. Well, probably wrong with the look of the button. However, using your Javascript code, nothing happens. In general, after 10 minutes look at the post, I'll try to show everything there.
//I prepared the text in advance, but it is not relevant, so just look at the post, it is updated

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put it in a form as suggested by  VilleKoo, you can also add a button to clear the value as below to clear the first input found of type text.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

html {
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    text-align: center;  
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    text-align: center;  
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial
}

input[type="text"] {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F1F1F1);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 0.5px;
    border-color: #ABABAB;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #ABABAB;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder       {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder                {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder                 {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder            {text-indent: 0px;   transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus::-moz-placeholder          {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus:-moz-placeholder           {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
input[type="text"]:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {text-indent: -500px; transition: text-indent 0.3s ease;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="asdf" class="clearable" type="text" placeholder="JUST TEXT BOX"/>
        <button value="clear" onclick='document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")[0].value=""'>Clear</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const handleMethod = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // clear input text
};
button.addEventListener(
  "touchstart",
  handleMethod,
  false
);
button.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  handleMethod,
  false
);
```

Like the above code, you can write a clear button yourself, and then combine the button with the input box